# error running bash command in Ubuntu shell

Tags: bash

I tried running this part of this bash code on Ubuntu using sh, but got a
"Syntax error: redirection unexpected" from the terminal. I included `#!/bin/sh`

```
   IFS=- read -r year month _ <<< "$entry"
```

How would I fix this? I am considering EOF but I am not sure how exactly to extract year and month characters from "$entry", which is a filename.

Comment: `<<<` is a bash extension, you're using `sh`.

Comment: Use `#!/usr/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: I still get the same error with #!/usr/bin/bash

Comment: `echo "$entry" | awk -F- '{print $1, $2}'`

Comment: `echo "$entry" | { IFS=- read -r year month _; echo "$year" "$month"; }`

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: using command sh file.sh

Comment: @Jetchisel how would I do this without needing to use echo, as I wont be printing to screen

Comment: Would I need to use the redirection symbol: | ?

Comment: then don't echo it. perform the operation you wan with the variablles inside the braces `{ }` since it is a subshell the values are lost outside, but in bash the `<<<` works so I'm not sure what/why are you getting the error.

Comment: I am using sh command, not bash command

Comment: @pdanh Running it with `sh` forces it to use the `sh` interpreter (ignoring the `#!` or "shebang" line), and [on Ubuntu that's `dash` rather than `bash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). Make the file executable (`chmod +x file.sh`), then run it directly (`./file.sh`).